# Data being returned from SQLite database not being assigned to a variable

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I have a method to return a token from an SQLCipher database that only contains one item.

```
fun checkForToken(context: Context, password: String): Token

    var returnToken = Token("", 0, "")

    SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(context)

    val databaseFile: File = context.getDatabasePath("$storagePath/IndyGoTest.db")
    val database: SQLiteDatabase =
        SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databaseFile, password, null)

    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Token(tokenType STRING, expirationDate INTEGER, accessToken STRING)")

    val query = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Token", null)

    query.use {
        if (it.moveToNext()) {

            with(query) {

                val returnTokenType = getString(0)
                val returnTokenExpiration = getInt(1)
                val returnTokenAccessToken = getString(2)

                returnToken =
                    Token(returnTokenType, returnTokenExpiration, returnTokenAccessToken)


                Log.d(TAG, "Expiration value returned from DB: $returnTokenExpiration")

                Log.d(TAG, "Expiration of token to be returned: ${returnToken.expirationTime.toString()}")

            }
        }
    }

    if (returnToken.expirationTime != 0 && returnToken.expirationTime != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Token retrieved from Database")
    }
    query.close()
    database.close()

    return returnToken

}
```

The item's values are being found, which allows the first print statement to succeed. However, when I try and pass those values into a new instance of my custom Token object, it isn't working, and the second log statement prints null. Here is my Token object (with Retrofit annotations):

```
class Token (tokenType:String, expirationTime:Int, accessToken:String){


@SerializedName("token_type")
@Expose
val tokenType: String? = null

@SerializedName("expires_in")
@Expose
val expirationTime: Int? = null

@SerializedName("access_token")
@Expose
val accessToken: String? = null
```

}

What is happening between the retrieval of the rows and creation of the object that keeps the values from being passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Token` class has a constructor taking three arguments but you're not doing anything with the values passed in.

In addition the class has three immutable properties that are initialised to `null`s.

To make the constructor arg values to be reflected in those property values, combine the two, e.g.:

```
class Token (
    @SerializedName("token_type")
    @Expose
    val tokenType:String, 

    @SerializedName("expires_in")
    @Expose
    expirationTime:Int,

    @SerializedName("access_token")
    @Expose
    accessToken:String) {}
```